# Kusto query: display only records with timestamp diff > 30 minutes

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a kusto table with the following columns:

```
{ timestamp, NodeId, flag }
```

This table is filled with new records every couple of minutes.

I want to filter out the NodeId for which the "flag" field remained FALSE for more than half an hour.

Is there a way to do this with a kusto query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter out the `NodeId` for which the `flag` field remained FALSE for more than half an hour, You can use the below query.

**Query:**

```
let myTable = datatable(timestamp:datetime, NodeId:string, flag:bool)
[
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:00:00), "Node1", true,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:01:00), "Node1", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:02:00), "Node1", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:03:00), "Node1", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:04:00), "Node1", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:05:00), "Node1", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:15:00), "Node1", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:20:00), "Node1", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:25:00), "Node1", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:30:00), "Node1", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:35:00), "Node1", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:00:00), "Node2", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:12:00), "Node2", false,
    datetime(2022-01-01 00:12:00), "Node2", True,
];
myTable
| order by NodeId, timestamp asc
| extend flag_change = iff(flag != prev(flag, 1, 0), 1, 0)
| serialize sub_group=row_cumsum(flag_change,NodeId != prev(NodeId))
| summarize duration = max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) by NodeId,sub_group
| where duration > 30m
| project NodeId
```

This query orders the rows by `NodeId` and `timestamp` by ascending order. Then computes the flag change in each row with respect to previous row. Then assigns a unique group number for each group of consecutive `NodeId` and `flag` value. It then summarizes the table by `NodeId` and `sub_group`, calculates the duration of each group, and filters the results to only include groups with a duration greater than 30 minutes.

[fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/ContosoSales?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA6WTP2+DMBDFdz7FNRNIjgSmXajo3qVTtqpCBg7iCmPkP01S9cPXEJLQDG2sgiVzJ//eE9a9Dg2Iw4aVHUIONTPudd+h4QK1YWLIXA/HisCLrPG5zrRRvG8JNB1rs1LKLgpeA3DP6WRIY0rXceIWxHE2rYjAauSTFQGjLJJfieSKaFin/0CoP5L6I/f+yIM3kvgj9PqOb0D8XVJ/l9Tf5ce80NtujP4f2UxT+fYYzHEIvkCqGhWUh3ny3eSeUgFMV+4A7g329ZSEotqyvh1DxJsmHDtwl8Og8GMqCCQERr9pc6hGxVnHPxG0LYtWSTvkSu6KygptRbiQJEf3s9yxjCYRKwRTo0htFTNc9s5fsP0lvhGsQfB+2bj8z9nZSe22qBYyT5DGwrUHJd+xMjPxDZYHoVcuBAAA)